# Good Open-Source Projects to be a Business App Programmer?

Tags: open-source

I was thinking of OpenOffice. Do you have any other suggestions of open-source projects that would be good or better to work on than OpenOffice if I were to be a business app programmer?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you consider to be a business app, and is your aim just to get a feel for what business application development is like?

Comment: I guess I consider a business app to be programs that business type/enterprise-level software programmers write.

My aim is just have open source experience on my resume when I'm in co-op. They say there are a lot of business programmer jobs...

Answer (score 2):

Actually I don't think OpenOffice is really what you are looking for, its not really representative of what most business apps are, thats more of an office automation thing and frankly most businesses just buy that, they don't develop it.

Probably what you want is some kind of CRM (Customer relationship management), POS (Point of sale), HR or Financial type system.

(Googling any of these terms gives plenty of hits)

Answer (score 0):

[Kexi](http://www.kexi-project.org/) might be a good project to work on.  Somewhat similar to OpenOffice Base, it strives to be a replacement for Microsoft Access (which I gather is being used for internal projects large and small throughout the business world.)

Answer (score 0):

If your business is financial services, maybe something like [OFX](http://xml.coverpages.org/ofx.html) would be up your alley.

Or maybe there are projects for helping to exchange medical history data.  Lots of stuff out there.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at this [list of ERP software packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ERP_software_packages).
There are some open source in there.